# Checking user on login against database wont work

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to check if a user is in my database and the username and password matches..
if it does then send him to rosta.aspx

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        { 
            using(spelnordDatabasEntities databaskoppling = new spelnordDatabasEntities())
                        {
                            var User = from s in databaskoppling.Anvandare
                                                where s.Username == login_betygsatt.UserName
                                             select s;
                            var Pass = from s in databaskoppling.Anvandare
                                                where s.Password == login_betygsatt.Password
                                                select s;

                            if (login_betygsatt.UserName == User.ToString() && login_betygsatt.Password == Pass.ToString())
                            {
                                e.Authenticated = true;
                                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(login_betygsatt.UserName, login_betygsatt.RememberMeSet);
                            }
                            else
                                e.Authenticated = false;
            }
        }
```

webconfig:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="loggain.aspx" defaultUrl="inloggad/rosta.aspx">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        </credentials>

      </forms>

    </authentication>
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error message? What is happening when you try to login? Also, I think you are assuming that `User` is a string representing UserName and `Pass` is a string representing password, but neither is the case.

Comment: Well the login-form just says that the login faild, i have tryd to set a break just before the if-statement and i cant se if i retrive the usernamne and password from my database.. :/

Comment: you're searching just based on the password in your second query. this would find any users that have the same password. i hope to god you're encrypting your passwords.

Comment: To add to what @DLeh said, you really need just one query with two conditions in the where clause, one for username and one for password.

Comment: lastly, you're getting a list of users / passwords. You need to take `.First()` or hopefully `.Single()` to find a single user you're trying to authenticate.

Comment: Ok, nice. But how can i check against the users input??

Comment: @user3727466 You are already checking against users input with your LINQ queries.

Comment: Like this??

where s.Username == login_betygsatt.UserName && s.Password == login_betygsatt.Password

Comment: I would really appriciate if someone could give me a exampel to work from, becuse im really dum right now...

Comment: @user3727466 Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having has to do with your implementation of the auth handler, specifically how you are searching for a matching user.

You want a query that will match against both the user-entered username and password, so:

```
var User = (from s in databaskoppling.Anvandare
             where s.Username == login_betygsatt.UserName
             and s.Password == login_betygsatt.Password
             select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

From there, you can just set `e.Authenticated`:

```
e.Authenticated = User != null;
```

Then, for the redirect:

```
if (e.Authenticated)
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(login_betygsatt.UserName, login_betygsatt.RememberMeSet);
}
```

Comment: Well i get a warning on the "and"-tag it says "a query body must end with a select claues or a group clause"

Comment: I get warning from and all the ay to s "and s.Password == login_betygsatt.Password select s" with different errors on the words.. cant understand why tho..

Comment: damn im stupid you should use || not and... sorry.. :(

Comment: It works now after some edit.
I have tested with a break and the linq finds the user BUT the redirect dont work..